# cxjs how to get all keys of an array or object in the selection?

Tags: reactjs, grid, cxjs

I have a List with Objects and I want to have the selection carry the complete Objects. Property selection does not work

how can i do this?

```
...
    records:bind="$myWindow.ObjectList"
    selection={{
                        type: KeySelection,
                        keyFields: ["Name","MyId","otherprops"], <--here i would need all my object properties. but i cannot list a hundret and they may change
                        bind: "$linkWindow.selectedObject"
                    }}
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selection should be based on the `id` field. When you need to access the record, you should find it the array. Alternatively, you can create a `computable`, like in the example:

https://docs.cxjs.io/concepts/controllers#computed-values

Comment: I need the selected Object in the model - i am not usind data binding here. so it is not a satisfying solution. but thanks anyways..

Comment: The problem with that approach is that if the data changes, the selection is lost.

Comment: Well. It is already working partly. When my object has has {a:1,b:{ba:2,bb:3},..} and I specify b as a keyfield, i get al children of b, too. The only thing I need in this case, is the whole object. and not only part of it. I use it in a dialog and do things in a controller method with it on click on a button.. so no data change risks exist.